Make Nginx "gzip_min_length" work for buffered chunked requests from upstream
I have an upstream server that I can't change, exposing two routes:

/api/bulk_get

returns some JSON content
knows the response length, so set Content-Length accordingly


/api/changes

returns some JSON content
use Transfer-Encoding: chunked as the response length isn't known beforehand, so Content-Length can't be set



The server listens on port 2626.
This is then exposed by Nginx (v1.20.x) used as reverse proxy:
location /api {
    rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:2626;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    gzip on;
    gzip_types application/json;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
}


For the route /api/bulk_get, Content-Length is known, so the gzip_min_length works fine.
For the route /api/changes, Content-Length is not present, so gzip_min_length isn't respected and all requests get compressed.

The thing is, Nginx buffers responses from upstream server (because proxy_buffering is on by default), so it knows the size of the response.
To schematize, we have
upstream ------------------------> nginx reverse proxy ---------------------> client
        Transfer-Encoding: chunked                      no Transfer-Encoding
                                   buffers the chunks                  receive several chunks at once

How can I configure the proxy, so that Content-Length gets computed on the buffered response, making the gzip_min_length work for the route /api/changes ?
